# How does slack store unread message counts?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, chat, slack

I'm building a chat application and I'm trying to identify the state architecture for indicating unread messages.

My state currently contains a list of messages. On render, I group them by conversation so I can render a list of recipients and, for the selected recipient, the messages.

The simplest approach would be to also store a `lastRead` hash of `{recipient: lastReadTimestamp}` in the state as well. On render, count the number of messages in each conversation whose timestamp is greater than the stored `lastRead` timestamp to get the number of unread messages. And when the recipient is selected, set the `lastRead` timestamp for that recipient to that of the most recent message.

The problem with this is if, while you're away, 15+ messages come in - to the point that some are beyond the viewport and you'd have to scroll to see them. Once you select that recipient, it will mark the `lastRead` timestamp as the most recent message, essentially marking the entire conversation as "read" even though there are messages above that haven't been seen.

Instead I was hoping to have functionality more like Slack's. [in-view](https://github.com/camwiegert/in-view) or an [InteractionObserver](https://github.com/WICG/IntersectionObserver) could detect when a message has actually come into the viewport.

[image: slack screenshot]

But what would I store in the state? The ids of each unread message? If so, when I refresh and my app receives all the messages, how does it know any of them are read? I could store the ids of each *read* message instead but that sounds unwieldy.

Has anyone seen a good design pattern for this?

Comment: How about using Activity stream? And custom field, viewed = true:false ? 
Read more about it http://activitystrea.ms/

Comment: Thanks @LukaKrajnc but couchdb is notifying the clients about the new message and that's working pretty well. Not sure what Activity Stream could add regarding persistent client-specific "read" status?

Answer (score 1):

We did use IntersectionObserver for exactly the same use case in a chat application.

**Pre-requests**:
The messages have 2 meta-fields:

- `time` (when it was sent)
- `timeSeen` (when it was viewed)

**The flow is as follows:**

- clientA sends a message via the server
- server appends `time = now()` and `timeSeen = null` to that message
- server saves the messages to the databases
- server forwards the message to clientB
- clientB checks that the message does not have `timeSeen`, e.g. it's `null`
- clientB renders the message inside an `IntersectionObserver` wrapped component, which triggers a hook when message is in viewport and passes the `messageId` as a param
- clientB sends a request to the server to mark the message as seen when requested by the hook
- server marks the message with `messageId` as seen by setting `timeSeen = now()`
- server sends an update to clientB with meta into on the message with `messageId` (timeSeen updated)
- clientB sees that timeSeen is not null anymore and does not call the hook on re-renders

I know this sounds a bit of an overkill, but this way you can reliably get the  following:

- All messages will have meta on when those where seen
- You can aggregate the unseen counters and lists on the server side based on the meta

Comment: Thanks! I’m not working on that project anymore, but it’s still an interesting problem. Does your solution work for group chats, or just 1-to-1 chats?

Comment: Mostly 1-on-1, for group chats we use a different approach.